# R function that uses the imported csv filename for exported csv, dynamically

Tags: r, function, csv

I am trying to write a R function which imports a .csv file, does some modifications on it (here removing the empty columns) and exporting the modified dataframe as a new .csv file. I have two issues:

1. I want the function to use the "primary.csv" file's name and add "modified" to it so the exported .csv file will be like "primary_modified.csv"
2. I want the function to work as a loop so I can run it for multiple dataframes simultaneously not one by one.

I appreciate you all.

here is what I have:

```
# create a function to remove all empty columns and save and write a new csv
removeEmptyCol <- function(x){
   df <- read.csv(x)
   colSums(is.na(df) | df == "")
   empty_columns <- colSums(is.na(df) | df == "") == nrow(df)
   df <- df[, !empty_columns]
   df[is.na(df)] <- ""
# need to change the file name for each dataframe 
   write.csv(df, "Trimmed-1.csv")
```

Comment: The first part of the problem is very easy. You just use a regular expression to replace the filename. 
Like: new_filename <- gsub("\\.csv$", "_modified.csv", original_filename)

Comment: Regarding the second part, a loop is by nature sequential, so it's not clear what you mean by 'simultaneously'. Do you want parallel execution without a loop? Or vectorized execution without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you make no reference to parallel processing elsewhere, I interpret your question as wanting a for loop that imports a .csv file, performs one or operation(s), and then exports the file before importing another .csv file and doing the same series of operations.

Here is a solution that uses tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
  
remove_empty_col <- function (dir) {
  files <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
  
  for (file in files) {
    
    new_name <- str_replace(file, "\\.csv$", "_modified.csv") 
    
    df <- read_csv(file)
    
    df <- df %>%
       select_if(~!(all(is.na(.)) | all(. == "")))
    
    write_csv(df, paste0(new_name)) }
  
}

out <- remove_empty_col("/dir/path/to/data/sets")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The code runs and works for the modification part but it does not change the csv file names. Any advice?

Comment: It exports a new, cleaned file with that name. In your directory should have the old version of the file, for example, "myfile.csv," and the new version, for example, "myfile_modified.csv." 

Do you instead want to overwrite the old file? And are you sure you want to destroy data?

Comment: For me it just overwrites the existing file with the same name! it might be related to the r version or something of that sort?

Comment: Hmm. I am definitely exporting a .csv file with _modified, while preserving the old version. Can you update your post to show a few files? Maybe there's a problem with the regex I provided versus the file names in your directory?

Comment: I finally managed to use your code. The issue was the name of one column in my csv files. the column name had a non-UTF-8 character. I corrected the column name and it worked perfectly. Thank you @generic.